# How to include a "." in the rmdir to remove a folder that has a dot on the name on command prompt

Tags: cmd, command-prompt

Im trying to filter the folders that i want to remove:

```
for /d %%G in ("C:\Users\andre\Desktop\Users\:*.") do rd /s /q "%%~G"
```

There is two folders in \Users

```
 abc
 abc.dfg
```

I just need to delete the "abc.dfg" and keep the "abc"
How can I add the "."(dot) to filter only the "abc.dfg" directory?

Comment: Is there really a colon within your path (…`\Users\:*.`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to the way wildcards are working in `cmd` (`*`= "zero or more" and `?` = "zero or one"), each wildcard-approach is doomed from the start.

`where` treats wildcards differently (`*` = "one or more" and `?` = "exactly one"), but works for files only, so you can't use it here.

That leaves you with checking if there is (not) an extension:

```
for /d %%G in (abc*) do if not "%%~xG" == "" ECHO rd /s /q "%%~G"
```

(remove the `ECHO` if the output looks ok)

Comment: In that case i need to delete a large amount of directories that the only thing they have in common in the name is the "."

I need to clear the C:\Users\
But i need to keep 3 directories:
     \Suporte
     \Publico
     \Default

All the other directories have dots on its name like:
     \siqueira.andre
     \boscatti.gian

Its the pattern lastname.firstname
Is it anyway that i can filter all the directories that has the "." on the name?

Comment: I don't understand. "Remove each folder that contains a dot" (a.k.a "has an extension")? That's exactly what my code does (minus the `ECHO` of course) Change `(abc*)` to `("C:\Users\andre\Desktop\Users\*")` to exactly match your question. (the `abc` came from the wording of your question. Now I realize they don't necessarily start with literal `abc`)

Comment: ... and `"%%~G"` to `"%%~fG"`

Comment: The dot its not an extension. The name of the folder contains a dot. For example: stephan.german and im trying to filter the folder that has a dot on its name

Comment: If a file or folder is named `stephan.german`, it has a base name of `stephan` and an extension of `.german`. It may not make much sense for us humans, but that's how the computer handles it. (Everything after the (last) dot *is* the extension *by definition*)